# A subadditive functional which is not a convex functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been thinking about this for a while now, is there a subadditive functional which is not a convex functional?

Comment: If $T$ is a subadditive functional which is homogeneous of order $1$, then it is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the real line $|\sin (x+y)| =|\sin\, x \cos\, y+\cos\, x \sin \,y| \leq |\sin (x)|+|\sin (y)|$ but $|\sin (x)|$ is not convex.

Comment: Sir, you're real good! (+1)